# How did the mountain range form in Galle crater?

Tags: geology, crater

In the [Galle crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galle_(Martian_crater)), there is a mountain range that is shaped like a circle segment that makes it look like a smiley face. How did this mountain range form? Is it a central ring that formed with the crater that then got partially eroded away? Or did it form after the crater? Or something else?

Comment: Are you asking about Galle on the Moon or Galle on Mars?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galle_(lunar_crater)    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galle_(Martian_crater)

Comment: @M.A.Golding There already is a link in the question to the wikipedia page of the crater I am talking about

Answer (score 4):

Rapidly!

Galle is a large (230km) crater. In the processes that occur in the aftermath of a massive impact, deep rocks can be pushed up. Often this creates a central peak, but it can also form a ring structure, as in this lunar crater:

[image]
[Schrödinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_(crater)), a large (312km) crater, near the south lunar pole.

The [Chicxulub crater](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/how-ring-mountains-forms-inside-crater) also has a similar ring structure. These complex crater structures form very rapidly, in a matter of minutes, as a result of the flow of rocks.  At the pressures and forces which occur in an impact, rock flows like a liquid.

The modelling of complex craters is difficult (it is hard to do an experiment!) but one reasonable model is that the ring forms as a wave generated by the collapse and terracing of the crater walls meets a second wave generated from the centre, as a central peak (which had previous formed) collapses.

The rings, as in the case of Schrodinger, may be incomplete, or reduced to just an arc and a couple of isolated peaks. : )

Comment: So there were two rings, and the inner one was reduced to an arc from erosion?

Comment: or the inner ring only partially formed, perhaps due to differences in the underlying rocks.  The process of crater formation is incompletely understood.